# ArrayList elements are lost after onDataChange

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have 100% guarantee that ArrayList is being populated because when I enter debugging mode, I can see that elements are properly added.
[image: Locations ArrayList with 3 elements]

But after finishing onDataChange block locations ArrayList is empty.

[image]

Here is my code, I will appreciate any ideas:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
public ArrayList<LocationObject> locations = null;
FirebaseDatabase database;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    locations = new ArrayList<>();
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    final DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("venues");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                locations.add(d.getValue(LocationObject.class));
            }
            Log.d("ELEMENT", String.valueOf(locations.size()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Connection failed");
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d("SIZE", String.valueOf(locations.size()));
    //Log.d("SIZE:", String.valueOf(locations.size()));
    mMap = googleMap;
    if(locations.size() != 0) {
        for (LocationObject o : locations) {
            double lat = o.getLat();
            double lng = o.getLoong();
            LatLng place = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place).title(o.getDesc()));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place));
        }
    }
    else{
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addValueEventListener and onMapReady are asynchronous functions, onMapReady could finish before that addValueEventListener.

Comment: Thank you, so what's the way to pass this ArrayList into onMapReady? How can I guarantee that locations ArrayList is populated before entering onMapReady?

Comment: you can call addValueEventListener after onReady Map. every time onDataChange executed, add (remove or changed) a marker